# UISrollView is desabled when keyboard hides in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I'm using the following code to solve the common issue when Keyboard overlaps UITextField in iOS:

```
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var activeField: UITextField?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

---

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    activeField = textField
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    activeField = nil
}
```

Keyboard Notifications

```
    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {

    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height , 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
}

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height + 8, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
}
```

It works as magic.

But I'm facing the following issue. When keyboard hides after text editing, the view goes back to its previous condition, which should be like this, but the scrolling becomes disabled. I can't figure out why.. I set the `scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true`, but it doesn't solve my problem.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: you should use IQKeyboaredManager to handle views when keyboard appears by using  IQKeyboaredManager u will not be in need of  handling it . IQKeyboaredManager will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong (well, the whole thing is wrong, but this is the particular line that you are complaining about):

```
let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)
```

Better would be

```
let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = .zero
```

Even better, when the keyboard shows, save the content insets. When it hides, restore them to the value you saved.

Comment: If I set contentInsets to 0, my view does not bounce down as soon as UITextField ends editing. That's the case

Comment: That's not what you asked. You complained that the scroll view was no longer scrollable when the keyboard hid. I explained why that was. As I said in my answer, your _whole_ code is wrong, so it cannot really be mended one line at a time like this.

Comment: maybe if you know the "right" code, you can share it? :)

Comment: The matter has been thoroughly discussed and explained here on Stack Overflow. There’s no need for me to repeat it. Search!